# Scapy BPF filter not working

Tags: python, scapy

I am using Scapy and would like to filter based on the destination mac address.

However, I am getting packets displayed where the destination MAC address is not the address specified in the filter.

Here is a code snippit:

```
from scapy.all import *

sniff(iface="eth1", filter="ether dst host 91:e0:f0:01:00:00", 
      count=3, prn=lambda x: x.show())
```

I am running Scapy 2.2.0

Any ideas on the issue here?

Comment: Consider formatting your code.

Comment: Formatting the code did not clear the issue.

Comment: Tried the code on my system, same version of scapy. The filter worked.  What kinds of MAC addresses are getting through the filter?

Answer (score 2):

Scapy requires numerous dependencies for many different systems. It is quiet possible that you don't have the required dependency for BPF filters to work.

http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/portability.html

Answer (score 2):

Installing tcpdump solved the problem for me - now the filter on sniff works

Answer (score 2):

In my case, upgrading to 2.3.3dev (github version), fixed it

Answer (score 0):

It's `scapy` fault!!! It seems that `scapy` starts receiving packets before applying the BPF filter (`filter` argument of `sniff` function). It takes a while to get work properly! 
Two methods to get rid of this:

1. Use `lfilter` to define your filtering function inside the script. It's not efficient on busy link because filter is applied in your script, instead of kernel. Consider using `pypy` to speed it up.
2. For some first packets check destination MAC address inside your script and then don't check it anymore; i.e check correctness of the packet in the beginning time of sniffing to pass unstable phase of `scapy` and then rely on `scapy` to filter the unwanted packets.

Comment: Sure, upgrading it seems to fix the thing