# Sniff() function is not filtering packets as mentioned in the option "filter"

Tags: python, scapy

I have a Python script that uses Scapy to sniff trafic.
I have this line

```
sp=input('please enter sourceport number')
s="tcp and port "+str(sp)
SYN=sniff(filter=s, iface="eth0",count=1,timeout=60)
```

The problem is that the result of that includes a NON TCP packet :

```
Ether / IP / UDP / DNS Qry "daisy.ubuntu.com."
```

What is the cause of this problem and how can I solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that issue. Can you try with the exact same filter with tcpdump and see if you get those UDP packets?

Comment: scapy uses `tcpdump` to compile filters. Is `tcpdump` installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12011089/3168666

Comment: All packages and dependencies are installed

Comment: @Pierre I will try it, I am not very accustomed to tcpdump

Comment: Use `tcpdump -n -i eth0 tcp and port xxx`. BTW when you use Scapy, do you have any warning output?

Comment: Also, can you try with the latest revision from the mercurial repository? (https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/overview)

Comment: @farfalla - to confirm - you want to see all TCP traffic over a certain port?

Comment: Drop the `and` in your filter and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks @RyPeck for your suggestion, I will try it as soon as possible and I will inform you about the result

Comment: @RyPeck, Although the filter isn't nice but it is correct. "port 80" means TCP or UDP port 80, so "tcp and port 80" is equal to "tcp port 80".

Comment: Consider my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011089/scapy-bpf-filter-not-working). I have tested it many times using different filters such as tcp, udp, ethernet, ip, etc.